# That actually sounds kinda gross

Tags: riddle

> Half of me is eight ups and a down 
>   The other half is yogurt, mixed all around 
>   I could be a rock star, or a Bachelor, although 
>   The best I'll probably get is "Sick reference, bro."

What am I?

After nearly a day, I figure I need to add some hints.

- There are exactly two words.
- It has nothing to do with food, but the two words individually can be associated with food (as per the first and second clues, naturally).
- Rock star is intentionally lower case, while Bachelor is intentionally upper case.
- The word 'reference' is a very important clue.

I ran this past a person who is a novice riddler but expert punster (and realistically, the two take a similar skill set) and she was able to solve it in about 10 minutes with minor coaching (i.e. the hints I included above). So it is definitely solvable!

Comment: is it some speciality Cocktail drink?

Comment: Possible solution to line one: 8 ups + 1 down = seven up

Comment: @Bishop so I guess a Seven Up mixed with Yogurt? All around Margarita?

Comment: @Kanchirk I thought mixed all around might be a hint that it is an anagram, but I am still struggling to figure that out. Rockstar could reference the energy drink

Comment: I can confirm that mixed all around literally means mixed all around, as in with a spoon or some such, and that rock star is intentionally left uncapitalized. It's funny that you say "Rockstar could reference..." because the word reference is incredibly relevant to this riddle.

Comment: @bishop I can also say (since this is taking suprisingly long, considering how fast riddles go on this site!) that your solution to eight ups and a down is correct.

Comment: Got ampersand in my head due to 7-up (& is above the 7 on a keyboard) and reference (& represents a reference in C++)

Comment: yogurt reminds me of spaceballs...

Comment: i have A7x stuck in my head cz of the first clue and the rockstar, I cant see how A or avenged would fit the second though. (or bachelor)

Comment: I have no idea what A7x is, but as I mentioned in an earlier comment, Bishop was correct in guessing the first clue refers to the beverage 7 up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be

> Pop culture

Since the first part references

> 7Up, a Pop

The second part references

> Yogurt, which is a grown culture

And the rest of it is

> references to pop culture, like rock star, game company, or Bachelor, a sitcom/tv show, and sick reference, which is used when someone makes a reference to pop culture.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/RG0BS1U.gif

Answer (score 7):

Are you a Yogurt Soju Cocktail?

Half of me is eight ups and a down

> 7-up

The other half is yogurt, mixed all around

> yogurt is yogurt~

I could be a rock star, or a Bachelor, although
The best I'll probably get is "Sick reference, bro."

> Soju is a alchoholic beverage. It's one of the most popular in korea, and the variety in alchohol content (16% to 45%) could represent the rock star and bachelor (Intensity reference). Sick reference could be because of the reference I just made, or because if you drink too much, you throw up and seem "sick".

Ingredients inside a soju cocktail:

> Soju, Yogurt, Lemon/Lime Soda (Sprite or 7up are popular)

Comment: While this is kind of cool, it is actually not related to food in any way.